# Product of scalar to matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let ${\bf A} = [a_{ij}] \in {\Bbb R}^{n \times n}$ be a matrix. If $k \in \mathbb{R}$ then $k {\bf A} = [ka_{ij}] $.

Also, we can consider $k$ as a $1 \times 1$ matrix,   $k {\bf A} =[ka_{ij}]$ is not a well-defined expression by consideration of the matrices' dimensions. I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: Alvو  I use $[k]$  as a $1\times 1$ matrix

Comment: "We can consider $A$ as $B$" does not mean we can replace $A$ with $B$ in every case. Basically it means there is a bijection between the set of $A$s and the set of $B$s, hopefully a "nice" bijection (with respect to some structure), but that's about all. For instance a complex number may be considered a polynomial modulo $X^2+1$, or can be considered a $2\times2$ matrix, but these representations aren't always interchangeable.

Comment: Alv, I don't use any  reference, i think we can use $[k]$ as as $1\times 1$ matrix

Comment: If you use a [Kronecker Product](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) instead of the standard matrix product, then both $k\otimes A\,$ and $\,A\otimes k$ are well-defined and are equal to what is typically represented by $\,kA\;$